# Keep getting errors and cannot achieve output

Tags: python, stack, queue

I'm trying to achieve this output but I got errors. I run my codes but got errors. I'm trying to do this:

> Call next customer.
>
> 1. Display that there is no customer in wait queue if the wait is queue is empty
> 2. Otherwise, display the queue number of the customer in the wait queue
> 3. If the customer responds to the call, he is removed from the wait queue and put into another 'customer served' queue, to indicate that the customer has gotten his food
> 4. Display a message to indicate that customer is being served

Expected output:

> Please choose: 1
>
> May I have your name: Fad

Errors I get when running:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-85165eb1f15c> in <module>
     44     choice = int(input("Please choose:"))
     45     if choice == 1:
---> 46         register(wait_que, que_num)
     47         que_num += 1 # queue number will be incremented by 1. so if 100, then after that is 101
     48     elif choice == 2:
<ipython-input-16-85165eb1f15c> in register(queue, qnum)
     15 def register(queue, qnum):
     16     name = input("May I have your name ")
---> 17     queue.append[qnum, name, 0]
     18
     19     pass
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable**
```

My code:

```
import random
from collections import deque
from time import sleep

print("Menu")
print("1. Register a customer")
print("2. Call next customer")
print("3. List customers in queue")
print("4. Exit")

def menu():
    pass

def register(queue, que_num):
    name = input("May I have your name ")
    queue.append[que_num, name, 0]
    pass

def call_next():
    if queue.empty:
        print("No customer in waiting queue")
    else:
        return 0
    pass

def list_cust():
    pass

wait_que = deque([]) # assign nothing to it
que_num = random.randint(1,5)*100
choice = ''

while choice != 0:
    menu() # print menu
    choice = int(input("Please choose:"))
    if choice == 1:
        register(wait_que, que_num)
        que_num += 1 # queue number will be incremented by 1. so if 100, then after that is 101
    elif choice == 2:
        call_next()
    elif choice == 3:
        list_cust()
    elif choice == 0:
        print("End of program")

    else:
        print("Invalid option...")
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` is a method for lists in python. Due to that, you have to use parentheses to utilize that functionality.

Change

```
def register(queue, que_num):
             name = input("May i have your name ")
             queue.append[que_num, name, 0]
```

to:

```
def register(queue, que_num):
    name = input('May i have your name ')
    queue.append([que_num, name, 0])
```